# How to turn Windows Proxy On/Off programmatically

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, proxy

I need a code to turn [Windows Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ5V3.png) on or off. I tried:

```
WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO proxyInfo;
proxyInfo.dwAccessType = WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY;
proxyInfo.lpszProxy = new WCHAR[25]  { 0 };
proxyInfo.lpszProxyBypass = new WCHAR[25]  { 0 };
WinHttpSetDefaultProxyConfiguration(&proxyInfo)
```

but it does not turn the proxy off even with administrator privileges.

Is there a winapi code that can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn Windows Proxy on,

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Wininet.lib")
void main()
{
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION options[2];
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST list{};
    list.dwSize = sizeof(list);
    list.dwOptionCount = 1;
    list.pOptions = options;
    options[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI;

    // Query the current value
    DWORD listSize = sizeof(list);
    InternetQueryOption(nullptr, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &list, &listSize);
    options[0].Value.dwValue |= PROXY_TYPE_PROXY; 
    list.dwOptionCount = 2;
    options[1].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
    WCHAR proxy[] = L"192.3.3.6";
    options[1].Value.pszValue = proxy;

    InternetSetOption(nullptr, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &list, sizeof(list));
    InternetSetOption(nullptr, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, nullptr, 0);
}
```

Turn Windows Proxy off,

Modify this line:

```
options[0].Value.dwValue |= PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT;
```

Comment: Thanks. `options[0].Value.dwValue = PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT; ` works for turning off. And `L"192.168.49.1:9099"` can be used to set the port. But still I have problem. I don't want to change the default value of proxy when I turn it on?